# Bootstrap: responsive, full screen stacked images (jumbotron)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a jumbotron that behaves like the one on the opening page of this site:
[Website](http://www.pascalvangemert.nl/)

No matter what size the viewport, it always fills the page with that gif and the rest of the site has sections which scale accordingly. Also no matter how you adjust the viewport, it does not distort the gif; it just re-scales or adjusts accordingly

I tried the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid special";>
  <div class="jumbotron" style="background: url(chillin.jpg) no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;" ></div>
</div>
```

But it distorts as you change the viewport. What am I missing, do I just need to add some media queries?

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your header?

Comment: yes I do have that line of script in my header

Comment: Have you looked at the `JS` code (thankfully it's not minified) behind the site you like?  I believe `applyResize()` function is responsible for adjusting the height of the `jumbotron`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `background-size` to 100%, you're telling the browser to stretch the background to fill it's container, which will cause undesired distortion. Instead, try using `background-size: cover`. This tells the browser to make the image as large as necessary to completely fill it's container without distorting the image. Another way to think about it is that `background-size: cover` will minimally "crop" the image until it fits perfectly in it's container. (As a side note, `background-size: contain` tells the browser to make the image as large as possible *without* cropping the image, but this will result in white space above or below the image if the container is not the same size as the image.)